# How to apply a hunk of changes in diff to current branch?

Tags: magit, git, diff

I have two branches, let's say branch `a` and `b`, I would like to apply some changes from `b` to `a`.

Note that I use `magit-diff` to show the differences between the two branches. Then I would like to apply some changes pointed out by `magit-diff` from `b` to `a`.

So, could please tell me how should I do this. Or is there better ways.

Answer (score 2):

Put the cursor on the change in question and press <kbd>a</kbd> for "apply". Also see [Staging and Unstaging](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Staging-and-Unstaging.html) and [Applying](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Applying.html) in the manual.